# Get ribboncontrols from ribbon programmaticallly

Tags: vsto, ms-office, ribbon-control, office-addins

i am developing vsto and i would like to hide some controls on the ribbon
Particulary i need to hide menu - Change Styles on styles group in home tab.
I tried to do it via xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabHome">
        <group idMso="GroupStyles">
          <menu idMso="ChangeStylesMenu" visible="0"/>
        </group>
      </tab>

    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

but menu is still visible
it looks like i cant get this control.
My question is anyone can get this control?
Via xml or via code?
By the way what is the way to get ribboncontrols programmatically.
I know that there is RibbonGroup class but i dont know how to load it(how to get it via id)
If i could do it i would get all items belongs to it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do so in C#:

```
// disable all controls in ribbon
foreach (RibbonGroup group in Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.MyTab.Groups)
{
    foreach (RibbonControl control in group.Items)
    {
        control.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Notice that `MyTab` is the name (controlID) of the tab in your ribbon.

Comment: I have two guesses on the answer above: 
1) For some RibbonControls you have to do more/other than set "Enabled = false". E.g. for a SplitButton you have to set "splitButton.ButtonEnabled = false"
2) The Disable-Function should be recursive because you can have child controls e.g. in a RibbonMenu-Control